# Calculating number of correct of multiple choice questions

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

I have data on questions which students answered. The format is such

```
Student     Q1   Q2  Q3    Q4
A            1   3   2    3
B            2   3   2    2    
C            1   2   1    2
D            3   3   1    2
```

For this example, lets say 1 is the correct answer for question 1, 2 is the correct answer for question 2,3 and 4.

How would I generate a statistic table that would tell me how many questions a student answered correctly? In the example above, it would say something like

```
Student    Answered Correct:
A          2/4
```

Comment: I'm a fan of the array solution - though in this case I would consider creating a custom function that returns the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of the correct answers, then just loop through the student answers to compare them.

I've created the final variable as character to display in the format you've shown. Obviously this means you won't have access to the underlying value, so you may want to keep the number of correct answers in the data for other analysis purposes.

```
data have;
input Student $ Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4;
datalines;
A 1 3 2 3
B 2 3 2 2
C 1 2 1 2
D 3 3 1 2
;
run;

data want;
set have;
array correct{4} (1 2 3 4); /* create array of correct answers */
array answer{4} q1-q4; /* create array of student answers */
_count=0; /* reset count to 0 */
do i = 1 to dim(correct);
    if answer{i} = correct{i} then _count+1; /* compare student answer to correct answer and increment count by 1 if they match */
end;
length answered_correct $8; /* set length for variable */
answered_correct = catx('/',_count,dim(correct)); /* display result in required format */
drop q: correct: i _count; /* drop unwanted variables */
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create variable `num_questions` and set it to the number of questions. Then you need to write as many `if-then-else` statements as questions to create binary variables (flags) to check if each answer is correct (e.g. `Correct_Q1`). Use `sum(of Correct:)` to get the total of correct answers for each student. `Correct:` references all variable names starting with 'Correct'.

```
data want;
    set have;
    num_questions = 4;
    if Q1 = 1 then Correct_Q1 = 1; else Correct_Q1 = 0;
    if Q2 = 2 then Correct_Q2 = 1; else Correct_Q2 = 0;
    if Q3 = 2 then Correct_Q3 = 1; else Correct_Q3 = 0;
    if Q4 = 2 then Correct_Q4 = 1; else Correct_Q4 = 0;
    format Answered_Correct $3. Answered_Correct_pct percent.;
    Answered_Correct = compress(put(sum(of Correct:),$8.)||'/'||put(num_questions, 8.));
    Answered_Correct_pct = sum(of Correct:) / num_questions;
    label Student = 'Student' Answered_Correct = 'Answered correct' Answered_Correct_pct = 'Answered correct (%)';
    keep Student Answered_Correct Answered_Correct_pct;
run;

proc print data=want noobs label;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have just four questions the fastest solution would probably be to just use conditional statements:`if Q1 = 1 then answer + 1;`
For a more general solution using a lookup/answer table:

Transpose the data, merge the answer table, summarize on student.

```
data broad_data;
   infile datalines missover;
   input Student $ Q1   Q2  Q3    Q4;
   datalines;
A            1   3   2    3
B            2   3   2    2    
C            1   2   1    2
D            3   3   1    2
;

data answers;
   infile datalines missover;
   input question $ correct_answer ;
   datalines;
Q1          1  
Q2          2  
Q3          2  
Q4          2 
;


data long_data;
    set broad_data;
    length question $10 answer 8;
    array long[*] Q1--Q4; 

    do i = 1 to dim(long);
        question    = vname(long[i]);
        answer      = long[i];
        output;
    end;
    keep Student question answer;
run;
proc sort data = long_data; by question student; run;

data long_data_answers;
    merge  long_data
           answers
           ;
    by question;
run;
proc sort data = long_data_answers; by student; run;

data result;
    do i = 1 by 1 until (last.student);
        set long_data_answers;
        by student;
        count = sum(count, answer eq correct_answer);
    end;
    result = count/i;
    keep student result;
    format result fract8.;
run;
```

If you like sql/want to compress your code you can combine the last two datasteps + sorts into one statement.

```
proc sql;
create table result as
    select student, sum(answer eq correct_answer)/count(*) as result format fract8.
        from long_data a
            inner join answers b
            on a.question eq b.question
        group by student
    ;
quit;
```